# Interesting C struct syntax/type

Tags: c, struct

I came across this in the Python interpreter source code.

```
void
PyThread_delete_key_value(int key)
{
    long id = PyThread_get_thread_ident();
    struct key *p, **q;
```

The interesting part being the `struct key *p, **q;` call. What exactly is this structure doing? I'm confused as to what exactly this is a struct of. Is this not the same as say, this?

```
struct 1 *p;
```

I are confused.

**Edit**:

Even though this has been answered, I should clear up my question. It was specifically the fact that the word `key` was reused and that I didn't know that the compiler considers them in different namespaces.

Comment: `struct 1 *p;` Is this even possible?!?

Comment: @karlphillip: No, it's not. Hence my confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

key exists in two different namespaces here.  Once as a variable, once as a structure.  The compiler knows that 'struct key' and int key are different things.

Comment: Thank you, this is the problem I was having understanding.

Answer (score 5):

`p` is a pointer to an object of type `struct key`. `q` is a pointer to a pointer of an object of type `struct key`.

You can define a structure like so:

```
struct key { int val; };
```

In which case the type is `struct key`.

The `key` after `struct` is part of the type (`struct key`), and not associated with the integer parameter `key`.

Comment: I think this is misleading. If one wrote `*p` in code, it would *not* be of type "pointer to an object...". It would be of type "object". The C language has this symmetry of declarations and expressions on purpose. (Though admittedly the original purpose may have been "re-use the same parsing code")

Answer (score 0):

First, the `int key` parameter has nothing to do with the `struct key` in the declaration. That is just an unfortunate naming collision.

Structs are in a different namespace though, so it works.

The line

```
struct key *p, **q;
```

Is declaring two variables.

The first is named `p` and is of type `struct key *`.
The second is named `q` and is of type `struct key **`.

The asterisk, denoting a pointer type, binds to the variable name *not* to the overall type in the declaration.

As an aside, as I commented in [mipadi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157706/interesting-c-struct-syntax-type/6157728#6157728), I had a professor who supposedly asked Kernighan (or maybe it was Ritchie) why it was the case that C expressions mirror their declarations in syntax. He said it was to be able to re-use the same parsing code. Apparently the C compiler was pretty close to being too-big-to-fit on the system it was written for.

It is nice sometimes, since you can be sure that if you have the declaration

```
int **foo[];
```

Then the expression

```
**foo[3]
```

Will be of type `int`, without having to think too hard about it.

Answer (score 0):

Those are pointers to struct. p is a point to key struct, and q is a pointer to a pointer of key struct. It is hard to tell what is going on here with out seeing the struct typedef or how the pointers are being used.